# MySQL query, three tables, outer join

Tags: mysql

EDIT: Answer:

```
SELECT c.Name FROM Country c
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT * FROM City 
JOIN Building ON City.CityID = Building.CityID 
WHERE City.CountryID = c.CountryID);
```

Thank you for your time guys.

I have schema like this:

[image]

I did something like this to select all cities with no buildings.

```
select * from City c 
  left join Building b on b.CityID = c.CityID
  where b.CityID is null or c.CityID is null
  union all
  select * from City c 
  right join Building b on b.CityID = c.CityID 
  where b.CityID is null or c.CityID is null;
```

**How to select names of countries with no buildings?**

Table description:
[image]

1. Data example:

[image]

2.Output expected:
England

Comment: you means city of country that not have building ?

Comment: country that not have building, it means if i have 4 buildings with folowing CityID - 1,2,4,4 then City with id=3 does not have building, that means if this city is for example London, and i have country England, there are no buildings (if england has london only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and tell me

```
 select * from country where CountryID not in
 (select CountryID from country as c   join city as t on c.CountryID =t.CountryID join building as b on t.CityID = b.CityID )
```

Comment: Unknown column 'c.CityID' in 'on clause'

Comment: Country don't have cityID FK, but City has countryID FK

Comment: Still the same :( Country has only countryID

Comment: give me some data and expected output

Comment: Ok I will put screen in first post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108526/discussion-between-asad-and-sovas).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT o.countryid
     , o.name country
     , i.cityID
     , i.name city
     , b.buildingid 
  FROM country o 
  LEFT 
  JOIN city i 
    ON i.countryid = o.countryid 
  LEFT 
  JOIN building b 
    ON b.cityid = i.cityid;
+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+------------+
| countryid | country | cityID | city      | buildingid |
+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+------------+
|         2 | England |      2 | London    |       NULL |
|         2 | England |      5 | Liverpool |       NULL |
|         4 | France  |      4 | Paris     |          5 |
|         3 | Germany |      3 | Berlin    |          3 |
|         3 | Germany |      3 | Berlin    |          4 |
|         1 | Poland  |      1 | Warsaw    |          1 |
|         1 | Poland  |      1 | Warsaw    |          2 |
+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

The final part of this problem has been left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Country.Name
FROM Country
JOIN City ON (Country.CountryID = City.CountryID)
WHERE City.CityID =
(SELECT City.CityID FROM City
JOIN Building
ON (City.CityID = Building.CityID)
WHERE City.CityID NOT IN Building.CityID)
```

Comment: @sovas: I don't have mysql setup to check the syntax, it was just like a sudo code to help you out